# Docker for Mac and VMWare Fusion

Tags: macos, docker, vmware, boot2docker, vmware-fusion

So I have Docker for Mac installed and I would like to use VMWare Fusion rather than VirtualBox. Doing a search, I came across `https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/vm-fusion/` using `docker-machine`. Not sure if that's what I'm looking for but when the Docker app starts I can see that the VMWare Fusion machine is suspended. Is there additional setup required to get new containers to run off of VMWare Fusion rather than VirtualBox?

Comment: Docker for Mac uses a native virtual machine implementation called [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) based on the osx [Hypervisor.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Reference/Hypervisor/index.html)

Comment: Thanks @Matt, that's the answer I was looking for if you want to resubmit it I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker for Mac actually uses a native virtual machine implementation called [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) based on the OSX [Hypervisor.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Reference/Hypervisor/index.html). Docker for Windows uses HyperV in a similar fashion.

Using a native VM implementation allows for tighter integration into the Docker app, rather than doing everything via Virtualbox's VBoxManage command as with the original boot2docker image and Docker Toolbox setup.